# Android emulator black screen in Windows Azure VM

Tags: android, android-emulator, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to run emulator on Azure VM, having OS Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter. Emulator started and stuck in black screen... Hyper-V in VM is already turned on... Anyone can help on this..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the emulators on win 8.1 pro or win 10 pro. I dont think the server 2012 r2 is supported completely with the emulator

Comment: Okay. Recently we have started working on Azure VM... and there is Server 2012 R2 only...